# XML drawable having different behavior on 4.3 and 4.1.2

Tags: android, android-drawable, xml-drawable

I have the folowing drawable,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="3dp"/>
    <padding android:left="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:top="1dp" android:bottom="1dp"/>
     <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#e4e4e4"/>

</shape>
```

"It supposed" to draw a border when set on background, actually on (Android 4.3 /goole nexus 7) it does , but unfortunately on (Android 4.1.2/ Samsung galaxy tab 10") it just fill all the background with the color

If someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong, or if someone has an xml drawable for border,
I will be very thankful :=)

Comment: increase your padding to `5dp` try

Comment: Ichanged the padding with the folowing:
<padding android:left="5dp" android:right="5dp" android:top="5dp" android:bottom="5dp"/>
but I have the same issue

Comment: i just tried and it works for me. i just changed the padding to 5p. increase your padding more and try. i tested it on a phone not on a tablet

Comment: strange :( for me even   when I remove the pading line completly I have this issue, thanks

Comment: I finally found a better drawable I put it as answer :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

here is the solution with the same drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    <corners android:radius="3dp"/>
    <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#e2e2e2"/>
</shape>
```

I needed just to specify  solid color :

```
 <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
```

Answer (score 1):

code of a border drawable that works better on both versions :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- This is the line -->
    <item android:top="1px" android:right="1px" android:left="1px" android:bottom="1px">
      <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
            <corners android:radius="3dp"/>
            <stroke android:width="1px" android:color="#e4e4e4" />
      </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```