# Android : Cardview Background is turning to black on 4.1.2

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface

I am using google cardView support library for my card functionality. It works well for kitkat and version up but however the background of card is set to black and padding/margins are not applied on device 4.1.2.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/all_goals_card_view"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
        >
 </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Have you got correct answer. I am facing same issue. Please help.

Comment: @Shiv I am supporting android version 4.4 and above for now.

Answer (score 44):

Okay, I just stumbled across the same issue and I found some devices to have some "special" very-light light-theming defaults *cough* samsung *cough* I will answer this slightly old queston.

The thing here is that you are most likely using the wrong `context` to inflate you layout. I think you are using the `application-context` to do so. Application-Context does not apply the theme you defined.

> This *(inflating with the application-context)* is legal, but inflation
>   will be done with the default theme for the system on which you are
>   running, not what’s defined in your application.*

For example if you do:

```
LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.menu_rental_list_item, parent, false);
```

**The `context` here should be an `Activity-` or `Fragment` `Context` - NOT the application-context.**

Please double check that.

*) Ah, you want to read more about contexts? Please continue reading [here](https://possiblemobile.com/2013/06/context/).

Comment: @Langusten Gustel thanks a lot. Another Samsung spesific weird behaviour, "sigh..."

Comment: Hello my dear, I think my question is the same. Can you take a look at it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56750943/android-toolbar-color-is-turning-to-blue-when-come-from-fragment

Answer (score 7):

don't use "@android:color/white"

```
card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#fff"
```

Comment: Doesn't makes any difference still the same output

Comment: @Sutirth please also change background color of any relative or linear layout inside cardview

Comment: @MuhammadHamzaShahid Simple stopped supporting those version :P

Comment: used `app:cardBackgroundColor="#fff"` though. but thanks.

Comment: someone can give me an explanation of the difference between #fff and @android:color/white (which is #ffffffff)?

Comment: @Massimo when use `@android:color` it use user android color code. maybe `@android:color/red` color code in android 4 be different with color code in android 7. it depend user android version

Comment: @RezaNazeri ok, but does it means that Android 4.1.2 has a black color in `@android:color/white`?

Comment: @Massimo no :) maybe very small different

Answer (score 3):

This will solve the issue:

```
      <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#fff"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#fff"
        android:layout_margin="2dp">
```

Notice these lines:

```
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

and 

card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#fff"
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on android 4.1.2 device. I was using an ImageView with shape drawable inside CardView which was the actual culprit.

Please check the answer in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18852709/xml-drawable-having-different-behavior-on-4-3-and-4-1-2) which helped me fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I put `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"` in the manifest file for related activity

Answer (score 0):

Don't use

> android:Theme.Dialog

or

> android.R.style.Theme_Dialog

, if your CardView is a part of the DialogFragment or Dialog layout.