# Cardview become inverted or black with white text

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-context, android-cardview

Like the title said it, the cardview become black with white texts, like inverted. Other cardview which not use Adapter is fine, though.

[image]

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7144646/5426412) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35923377/android-cardview-background-is-turning-to-black-on-4-1-2) but doesn't work. Google doesn't show much result with same situation.

In fragment:

```
allGroupsView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.allGroupsView);
adapterGroup = new AdapterGroup(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), results);
allGroupsView.setAdapter(adapterGroup);
allGroupsView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext()));
```

As in `AdapterGroup`,

```
public AdapterGroup(Context context, List<DataGroup> results) {
    this.mContext = context;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    this.data = results;
}
```

The links hinted about Context so my guess is I used it wrongly. After going around with context, none of it works. Is there something I missed?

Comment: What styles are you applying to these views? Looks like the "inverted" views are styled with Theme.Material, rather than Theme.Material.Light.

Comment: I use AppTheme style. I changed the xml for cardview to Material.Light but still inverted

Answer (score 0):

In my case i change:

`mRambuAdapter = new RambuListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),mListRambu);`

To

`mRambuAdapter = new RambuListAdapter(this,mListRambu);`

> The context here should be an Activity- or Fragment Context - NOT the application-context.

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39882195/3086112